# Does apt-cache policy <package_name> require sudo?

Tags: package-management, permissions, apt-cache

Can't find any formal explanation to determine whether `apt-cache policy <package_name>` command requires `sudo` or not.

Tested it in my machine (Ubuntu) with lots of packages and seems to work, but I'd like to know if there's an scenario where this does not work.

Comment: No it doesn't make any changes, and `sudo` is not required.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't make any changes and only grabs public details from your system (also available via http://packages.ubuntu.com/ with a browser though not as useful or machine specific as `apt-cache` provides) so `sudo` is not required.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `apt-cache policy <pkg>`, it:

- checks the repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` to get all the enabled respository addresses
- based on the above list, gets all the packages matching the pattern from each repository packages file -- these reside in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`
- it also checks `/var/lib/dpkg/status` to get the installation info for the package

It also does some other stuff but not important to go into the details of those.

Now, all it needs is the user has:

- *read-execute* permissions for the directories (starting from root leading to it, including all subdirectories)
- *read* permission on the relevant files

all the directories mentioned have *read-execute* by default for *others* with files having *read* for *others*.

As a result, on a default installation of Ubuntu, any user would be able to run `apt-cache policy <pkg>` without needing any special privilege.

FWIW the binary `apt-cache` itself has the permission `0755`, so is executable by anyone.